# Create two or three columns spreadsheet having multiple rows?

Tags: pdfclown

I understand that table and cells are supported only in PDFClown version 2.0 but that is only a few months away.  So, being stuck with version 1.2, how do I create a spreadsheet having 2 columns (& another spreadsheet having 3 columns)?

Anything with examples to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, [the layout engine supporting tables and lots of other high-level typographic elements is scheduled for 0.2.0](http://pdfclown.org/2014/09/12/waiting-for-pdf-clown-0-2-0-release/#ContentCompositionEngine) (its Java implementation will be pre-released for evaluation and beta-testing); in the meantime you can coarsely arrange a table this way:

1. **define the table partition (columns)** on the page and draw the corresponding rectangles through the PrimitiveComposer;
2. **insert in each column area your contents** through BlockComposer, keeping track of the maximum y occupied by your contents (this is calculated when you call BlockComposer.End(), after which you can retrieve the bounding box of your contents via BlockComposer.BoundBox);
3. when you complete the columns for the current table row, use the maximum y saved in step 2 to **draw the bottom line which closes the row** and iterate back to step 2 until you run out of rows;
4. **if you run out of space while inserting contents**, keep track of the positions returned by BlockComposer.ShowText() and BlockComposer.ShowXObject(): this way you can fill each column, then move to the next page and resume the insertion according to the tracked positions.

This should suffice to get the job done. ;-)

Comment: Based on your `Answer` description, I found this example in `*\dotNET\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli\TypesettingSample.cs`, hope it is sufficient enough to use while learning with trials & errors.

Comment: Regarding Java implementation for pre-release for evaluation & beta-testing, so there wouldn't be a C# version for that?

Comment: @fletchsod C# version will come during summer.